# How can I reorder columns in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

so I fill my DGV with some data and set some columns invisible:

```
        var part = inventory.espiromex_product.Where(p => p.descriptionsmall == cmbMainP.Text).First().partnumberp;
        dtgAssy.DataSource = inventory.espiromex_productsub.Where(p => p.partnumberp == part);
        dtgAssy.Columns["idproductsub"].Visible = false;
        dtgAssy.Columns["partnumberp"].Visible = false;
        dtgAssy.Columns["partnumbersubp"].Visible = true;
        dtgAssy.Columns["quantity"].Visible = true;
        dtgAssy.Columns["comments"].Visible = true;
        dtgAssy.Columns["assemblyno"].Visible = false;
        dtgAssy.Columns["assemblynodesc"].Visible = false;
        dtgAssy.Columns["uomid"].Visible = true;
        dtgAssy.Columns["subassemblylevelnumber"].Visible = false;
        dtgAssy.Columns["scrappercent"].Visible = true;
```

this is just fine but columns are sorted Alphabetically, How can I reorder columns programmatically?

note that inventory is an Entitie and I am using Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the [DisplayIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex(VS.80).aspx) of the individual columns.

Answer (score 7):

Another suggestion: don't let the datagridview make decisions for you.  Instead of letting the dgv automatically generate columns for you at binding time, write the code to create the columns in the order you want and with the attributes you want and then bind the data source.  Relying on the dgv to do the work can create unpredictable results as new versions come out or you make subtle changes to your data source.

Comment: As long as the queries don't rely on `SELECT *` then the order of the columns will be very consistent and won't be affected by changes subtle enough to not break your queries.

Comment: I prefer a deterministic approach.  If you want a specific behavior, code for it.  Don't rely on semi-predictable but not guaranteed behavior.