# C# DataGridView columnindex and visual display

Tags: c#, datagridview

There is a datagridview table, c# language.
Consisting, for example, of 6 columns. It is necessary to add the seventh, but not to the end of the table, but to the third place.
But because of this, you will have to rewrite a lot of code, because the column indexes will shift.
I'm interested in the question: is it possible to visually display a column in the third position, and refer to it as 7?*

*I understand that indexes start from zero and will be 2 and 6 respectively.

Screens:

[Table columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UCPQ.png)

[Visual display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvexr.png)

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reorder columns in a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858580/how-can-i-reorder-columns-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: That being said, try not to rely on the column index too much in case you do want to change the actual order of the columns. For example, instead of `dgv.Columns[0].Width = 100;`, you'd use something like `colTitle.Width = 100;` and instead of `dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0]`, use `dgv.Rows[0].Cells[colTitle.Index]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: *Is it possible to visually display a column in the third position, and refer to it as 7?* and the answer is **yes**.

As a suggestion, what works best for me is to not deal with the `int` index at all, but to use the `string` indexer of `Datagridview.Columns` and use `datagridview.Columns["columnName"]` to refer to individual columns. This solves the problem of having to rewrite code when the index changes from an insert (as you mentioned) because you refer to columns by name.

Sometimes you know what all the possible column names might be. In this case, you can make this even more robust by abstracting them out to an enum:

```
enum StdColumnName
{
     Apple0, 
     Orange1,
     Banana2,
}
```

**Example** [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dgv_columns_order.git)

Override this method in MainForm:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StdColumnName)))
    {
        var col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = name,
            HeaderText = name,
            AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill 
        };
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
    }
}
```

to get this:

[image]

then click the button:

```
private void btnChangeOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var col = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(StdColumnName.Banana2)];
    col.DisplayIndex = 0;

    Debug.WriteLine(
        $"The Banana2.Index is { dataGridView.Columns[nameof(StdColumnName.Banana2)].Index}");
    Debug.WriteLine(
        $"but Banana2.DisplayIndex is { dataGridView.Columns[nameof(StdColumnName.Banana2)].DisplayIndex}");
}
```

to get this:

[image]

Now `col.Index` and `col.DisplayIndex` are two different numbers but using the name still works.

Hope this give you a few ideas.